# Altium view does not show lower part of PCB

Tags: altium

In Altium Designer 16.0, very intermittently, the GUI does not let me navigate towards the lower part of the PCB, somehow freezing the lower part of it, unable to move anything to there, like the windows were "saturated" or limited to see the lower Y coordinates of the PCB.

The following operations do not affect this "bug":

- Changing the origin,
- Restarting the program,
- Reopening the PCB,
- Fit Document View,
- Dragging an object into the "offending" zone (the GUI is again "saturated")

This affects the 2D View Edition of a PCB.

Anybody have a suggestion?

Comment: This really sounds like an Altium software bug, rather then an Electronics Engineering question. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds to me like you have your PCB located at or near the absolute origin. The origin you can move is called a "relative origin" and moving it does not change the absolute origin. Before starting a design, I always move my relative origin far away from the absolute and build my board around that, rather than down in the bottom left corner of the workspace. This allows full navigation of the entire board without running into the absolute origin. Before I started doing this I had the same problem you are seeing. To confirm whether or not your board is well within the workspace, watch the coordinates at the bottom of the screen as you mouse over or near the "frozen" part of your board. If I am correct, the Y coordinate (and probably the X coordinate as well) will be low or zero. I'm not sure if it would show negative numbers.

**UPDATE:**
After testing this out at work it looks like the coordinates at the bottom of the screen are based off of your relative origin, so not necessarily of much use here.  However, as your cursor reaches the absolute origin you will notice the numbers stop changing as you continue to move down and left. That will help you pinpoint its location, and give you an idea where you need to stay away from.

Answer (score 2):

If this is the same issue a coworker of mine had a while ago, then you should hit "Ctrl A" to select everything and drag everything inside and out of the "offending zone" away from the offending zone. then just work as normal away from the offending zone.

the issue is that in altium parts can go outside of the accessible workspace and become unselectable with normal clicks.